# How to subscribe to a specific child route parameter?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have these two route definitions, product list and product detail:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    ...
    {
        path: 'product',
        component: ProductListComponent,
        resolve: {
            products: ProductListResolverService
        },
        children: [
            {
                path: ':productcode',
                component: ProductDetailComponent,
                resolve: {
                    product: ProductDetailResolverService
                }
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
    ...
```

Inside the product list component I have a set of radio buttons to indicate which product is selected, while the router outlet displays the product detail component:

```
<div *ngFor="let product of Products" class="radio">
    <label>
        <input [(ngModel)]="SelectedProduct" 
            [value]="product" 
            (change)="RefreshDetail()" 
            name="selectedProduct" 
            type="radio"> 
            {{product.Name}} {{product.Code}}
    </label>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

When the user clicks the radio button, the URL, the product detail component, and the radio button are synchronized correctly.

But when the user goes directly to a certain product URL, the URL and product detail component display the correct product, but the radio button doesn't. What I mean by going directly to a certain product URL is the user inputs the URL to the browser address bar and press enter.

I tried to get the value of `:productcode` from ActivatedRoute but it didn't work:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  let productcode = params.get("productcode");

  let product = this.Products.find(product => product.Code == productcode);

  if (!!product) {
    this.SelectedProduct = product;
  }
});
```

The `paramMap.get("productcode")` is always null. Probably because it is not available in the product list route, but in the child route, the product detail route.

I haven't found a way to subscribe to product detail route from product list component. Besides product detail route is not the only child of product list route.

How do I subscribe to a specific child route parameter?

Answer (score 3):

One of the better way is to use the service and  `observable`. So that, whenever the child component changes, the new data will get immediately reflected in the parent component (especially when u refresh the page you can retain your parent component status).

In your ProductDetailComponent,

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';


export class ProductDetailComponent {
    private subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute, private productService:productService){
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
      let vm = this;
      this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
          (param: any) => {
            if(typeof param['productcode'] !== 'undefined' && param['productcode'].trim !='' &&  typeof param['productcode']!=null){
               vm.productService.changedProductCode(param['productcode']);
            }
      });
    }
}
```

in your product.service.ts,

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class myService {

  private productCode = new Subject<string>();

  productCodeChange$ = this.productCode.asObservable();
  changedProductCode(option:any){
        this.productCode.next(option);
  }
}
```

Now, to get the changed product id in your parent component,

ProductListComponent.ts

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { ProductService } from './product.service';

export class ProductListComponent {

    private subscription:Subscription;

    constructor(private productService:productService){

        this.productService.productCodeChange$.subscribe( /* get called on every child page changes*/
         code => {

        console.log(code); // you get your passed code value in 'code' variable

        let product = this.Products.find(product => product.Code == code);

        if (!!product) {
          this.SelectedProduct = product;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {

    let productcode = params['productcode'];

    let product = this.Products.find(product => product.Code == productcode);

    if (!!product) {
       this.SelectedProduct = product;
    }
});
```